# tqdm progress bar doesn't show up while downloading with requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, tqdm

I'm trying to show a progress bar with tqdm while downloading a file with python requests library. But it doesn't show the progress bar. It shows this

```
22964708: 2804it [00:13, 204.17it/s]
```

And this is my code:

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open("downloads/" + name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192),r.headers.get("content-length")):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Could you please give use your `url` in order to test? :)

Comment: @B.Gees Sure: https://hw15.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/d488ada4bfdabc86fbfa9e3d576846a512886077-144p__93233.mp4

Comment: and your `name` is not defined ;)

Comment: @B.Gees name does not matter. It can be "askjdajskd".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the code that shows progress bar while downloading:

```
from tqdm import *
import requests
url = "your url"
name = "video"
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        pbar = tqdm(total=int(r.headers['Content-Length']))
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                pbar.update(len(chunk))
```